# 'gitlab-runner' unexpectedly runs as root

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm new to continous integration on iOS,
I try to run build with `gitlab-runner` and use `shell` as executor but I got issue that `pod cannot run as root` I am sure that I am not installing cocoapods with sudo and I try run `whoami` at `before_script` and that's right my runner run as root
[image]

How can I make `gitlab-runner` not run as `root`?

Comment: @BhaveshDhaduk Left menu CI / CD ~> Jobs

Comment: @BhaveshDhaduk create your runner first at Settings ~> CI/CD ~> Runner Settings and make sure your Gitlab runner on your machine running

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Register the runner without sudo, and that should set the `gitlab-runner` to run as your current user.

So steps should be:

```
sudo curl --output /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/binaries/gitlab-runner-darwin-amd64

sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner

gitlab-runner register ...

gitlab-runner install
```

Remember to stop your sudo `gitlab-runner` service otherwise you could have multiple runners on the same machine fighting for the same jobs.

Answer (score 3):

Here is [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/) for how to use `sudo` and `gitlab-runner` user.
I am not sure, but I think it creates multiple runners.

On **CentOS 8** I modified the `gitlab-runner.service` and changed the `--user` option to `root`.
Here  is the default configuration:

```
/usr/bin/gitlab-runner run --working-directory /home/gitlab-runner --config /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml --service gitlab-runner --user gitlab-runner
```

or

```
root@server# cat /etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service
[Unit]
Description=GitLab Runner
After=syslog.target network.target
ConditionFileIsExecutable=/usr/bin/gitlab-runner

[Service]
StartLimitInterval=5
StartLimitBurst=10
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gitlab-runner "run" "--working-directory" "/home/gitlab-runner" "--config" "/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml" "--service" "gitlab-runner" "--user" "gitlab-runner"

Restart=always
RestartSec=120

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and I changed to this:

```
[Unit]
Description=GitLab Runner
After=syslog.target network.target
ConditionFileIsExecutable=/usr/bin/gitlab-runner

[Service]
StartLimitInterval=5
StartLimitBurst=10
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gitlab-runner "run" "--working-directory" "/home/gitlab-runner" "--config" "/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml" "--service" "gitlab-runner" "--user" "root"

User=root
Group=root

Restart=always
RestartSec=120

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So this part `--user gitlab-runner` to `--user root`

## NOTE

Absolutely I did not have security concerns, and did it for test, **plase make sure you are considering security part**.